# On the mac, what is the difference between xattr and chflags

Tags: macos

To me they seem to be doing some very similar things and I do not understand why there are two distinct commands.

Comment: would be nice if whoever voted to close this would write an explanation as to why; can't understand why it's not even mandatory when voting to close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chflags` is a BSD-subsystem command that let change additional flags a file system may support natively. Historically, this is a kind of basic file mode extension support in BSD system, by using non-used bits in the metadata native filesystem. As MacOS is built on top of a BSD-flavour, `chflags` is supported (but a few extensions are supported). Values you can manipulate through `chflags` are predetermined.

`xattr` is a tool to manipulate user meta data associated to files. These metadata can be far more rich than simple on/off setting. Implementation of this is free, even if many filesystem have a special support for this. Historical HFS+ mac filesystem has a special support for this in the so-called named-forks. There is no limitation on kind/number of metadata that can be associated to a given file. The filesystem is unaware of these metadata content, it is just another kind of storage. That may be the OS or tools that in some context need to have access to these. For example I can add any such metadata I want to a given file :

```
$ ls -ail myfile
8607162443 -rw-r--r--  1 yunes  staff  0  6 jui 16:50 myfile
$ xattr -w mydata myvalue myfile %now my file is associated with some metadata
$ ls -ail myfile
8607162443 -rw-r--r--@ 1 yunes  staff  0  6 jui 16:50 myfile
$ xattr -l myfile %let me know which are the metadata associated to a given file
mydata : myvalue
$
```

So the system stored those metadata somewhere (it may use the help of some filesystem support for this or some ordinary file appropriately named, ever saw those strange `._` prefixed files?) but the data means nothing to the filesystem. Some tools may use thus to do something special...

Comment: You'll see them if you use `ls -l@` instead of just `ls -l`.

Answer (score 1):

`chflags` manages a small number of specific flags that are known by the operating system (such as "hidden"). These are stored in a bitmask, similar to `chmod` values. It is fairly old, going back to BSD 4.4 (1994).

`xattr` manages generic key-value metadata and comes from the HFS+ filesystem. Any application can attach arbitrary metadata and may interpret it in any way that it likes. I believe the feature was added in 10.4 (2005).